# Moving back to the front or end of a long URL entery with out having to use delete?

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation

Is there a way to move to the front or back of a long sentence you type in the URL area on a iPhone with out having to get close as possible and then having to delete then retype?

Comment: Are you referring to something like [trackpad mode in iOS](https://www.cultofmac.com/557965/ios-12-brings-trackpad-mode-to-every-iphone-and-ipad/)?

Comment: In addition to what @fsb said, you can also [move the cursor to exactly where you want to put it](https://snapguide.com/guides/move-the-cursor-on-iphone-exactly-where-you-need/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just checked it on my iPhone, and have been using it on my iPad for awhile.

On an iPhone you have to do a long press(or 3D press) on the keyboard (Trackpad mode, thanks @fsb for its official name), this turns the whole keyboard into a trackpad bound to the text cursor. 
The keyboard will turn grey and the letters will disapear. You can now move your finger and it will move the text cursor.

[Demonstration on Youtube.](https://youtu.be/XlcCgiYF2Fs?t=17)

On the iPad it works with 2 fingers together as well.

The other method is holding your finger down when trying to select a spot in text till a magnifier pops up, but that is not as easy with URLs.

Comment: Thank you, So I think what your saying is I would need to have a iPhone with the Trackpad ability. I have a iPhone 8 and I do not see that I can use it as a Trackpad. If that is so, then that could be why my MacBook Pro trackpad stopped moving the curser as normal.

Comment: The iphone 8 has the ability. On the digitial keyboard, press down and wait a second, the keybaord will go grey out and the keys will not show the keys anymore, you can now move your finger around and that moves the cursor in the text.

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I'm here for the same question but I somehow found a faster solution.

Suppose you have a long url or text that you're typing and you want to go to the beginng of the text quick. You can do the following:

1. Tab the text
2. Tab the "Select All" option
3. Hold the "space" key on the virtual keyboard

Voilà! The cursor is now at the beginning of the text. Enjoy!